# How can i display price in woocommerce product table with custom query?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to save the product with meta fields and it works perfectly fine. But the problem that I am facing is the price is saved but not displayed in the table. But when I edit the price and hit update then it displays correctly.

Here is my code. Please let me know where i am wrong.

```
function create_simple_product($array = array(), $upgrade = false)
{
    $user_id = get_current_user();

    if ($upgrade) {
        $array = array_map('convertNameAndSKU', $array);
    }
    $post_ids = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $v) {

        $title = $v['name'];
        if ($upgrade) {
            $title = '+ Additional ' . $title;
        }

        if (!post_exists($title)) {

            $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
                'post_author' => $user_id,
                'post_title' => $title,
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => "product",
                'post_category' => array(74)
            ));

            $price = $v['price'];
            if ($upgrade) {
                if ($price > 1) {
                    $price = $price / 2;
                }
                $price = ($price * 75) / 100;
            }

            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_visibility', 'visible');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_downloadable', 'no');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', number_format($price, 3));
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_purchase_note', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_featured', 'no');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_weight', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_length', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_width', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_height', '');
            if ($upgrade) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $v['sku'] . '-' . 'upgrade');
            } else {
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $v['sku']);
            }
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_sold_individually', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_manage_stock', 'no');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_backorders', 'no');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', '');

            array_push($post_ids, array(
                'count' => (int) explode('-', $v['name'])[1],
                'pricing' => number_format($v['price']),
                'link' => '/?add-to-cart=' . $post_id,
                'popular' => false,
                'discountpercentage' => 25,
            ));
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($post_ids);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided code, it seems that the issue lies in the way the price is being saved in the WooCommerce product meta fields. The `_price` meta field, which is used to display the product price in the table, is being updated with an empty value, which is why it's not displayed correctly.

To fix this, you need to update the `_price` meta field with the actual price value. You can do this by adding the following line before the end of the `foreach` loop:

```php
update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', number_format($price, 3));
```

This line will ensure that the `_price` meta field is set with the correct price value before saving the product.

Your modified code should look like this:

```php
// ... (previous code)

foreach ($array as $key => $v) {

    // ... (previous code)

    if (!post_exists($title)) {

        // ... (previous code)

        // Update the _price meta field with the actual price value
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', number_format($price, 3));

        // ... (previous code)

        array_push($post_ids, array(
            'count' => (int) explode('-', $v['name'])[1],
            'pricing' => number_format($v['price']),
            'link' => '/?add-to-cart=' . $post_id,
            'popular' => false,
            'discountpercentage' => 25,
        ));
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($post_ids);
echo '</pre>';
```

With this modification, the product price should be displayed correctly in the table without needing to edit and update the product again.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did a very silly mistake

Comment: Hey, my category is also not working. Can you please review this again